# Echoing php in php

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

im having an problem, currently im using a code to alter page content.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ad']) && $_GET['ad'] == 1)
{
echo "";
}
else {
echo '<div class="ad-area"><p>This is the ad, click here</p> </div>';
}
?>
```

But now I face a problem, since I need to display another URL and it echos from wordpress custom field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="link" value="<?php echo $linkk; ?>?kw=<?php echo $_GET['kw']; ?>" />
```

What I would like to see is that if url has

> ad=1

inside it,

> $linkk would be $linkk2

, but im unsure how to do it, cause echoing just displays the code, cause its server side. Since its a page template and the URLs change, then I cant just insert them into the code.

What to do?

Thanks,
M

Comment: Where do `$linkk` and `$_GET['kw']` comes from? And do you trying to do this in template file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="link" value="'.$linkk.'?kw='.$_GET['kw'].'" />';
```